# Reset root navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following navigation arborescence:
[image]

I want to reset my SwitchNavigator (root), which would reset all my nested navigators, and then go to SignInScreen.

I lost a lot of hours and tried a lot of things. It seems that before, we could use

```js
NavigationActions.reset({
    key: null,
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SignIn' })],
  })
```

But in the actual version of react-navigation, `reset` is not available from `NavigationActions` but only from `StackActions`. I mean, I want to reset my root navigator, not only my nested `StackNavigator`.

In the issues from `react-navigation` I saw that if the key was `null` the root navigator was reset. So I tried like this :

```js
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
            key: null,
            index: 0,
            actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName: 'SignIn',
                }),
            ],
        }));
```

I don't know if it works, because I can't go from my `ProfileScreen` (the screen from which I want to logout) to `SignInScreen`, I have this Error:

**Error: There is no route defined for key SignIn.
Must be one of: 'ProfileScreen'**

So, my question is the following :

### How to unmount all the screens of my app (while logging out) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`createSwitchNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html):

> By default, it does not handle back actions and **it resets routes to their default state when you switch away**.

So, all you really need to do is navigate to your `SignIn` screen.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')
```

However, since it says there's no route defined for that key, then you should make sure that that is the correct route name defined in `AuthStack.js`.

Comment: Thanks dude, why am I always looking too far... I thought the problem was with the navigation but it was with the way I managed my token, I got `unauthorized` and that's why my app had a different behaviour after a logout